# Speaker only outputs audio from the left

Tags: windows-10, audio, speakers

Problem: My (Singular) speaker underneath of my desk will only output audio from the left channel, And none from the right.

I only have hd audio 2nd output, how do I split the front and back audio jacks?
I spent a solid hour looking up ways to do it, usually I see things like this (found this on a forum):

[image: (Found this on a forum)]

Sadly I only have one output really, HD Audio 2nd output (Realtek high definition audio), there is a second, though it goes to my internal computer speaker. In which it is barely audible and barely used. I have tried the "Mute internal output device when an external headphone plugged in" option, the same problem occurs.

It may be that my device is outdated or something similar, I would just like to know if that is the issue or if its even slightly possible. But the issue mainly is I would like to split the audio jacks or have my speaker play left and right audio instead of only left.

Drawn up example:

[image: (Drawn up example)]

More specifically, when I click left, my headphones play left audio and so does the speaker, when I play right it only plays my headphones. It isn't that overall bad, but it would be a lot nicer to have.

Another solution might to be able to turn the Speaker to mono, it is a single speaker. Anything would work. I have tried all the jacks, the two ones that go out behind the computer, and the one in front. There are two in front, though one is reserved specifically for microphones, which I understand.

This is very specific, but I hope anybody out there knows what I'm talking about.
Oh and to note, I have tried Headphone virtualization, it has worked and solved my problem, but the right audio channel is still very diminished. I would still want to split my back and front audio jacks into two separate output devices.

Answer (score 2):

If you physically only have one speaker, you need to set that output to mono. That will properly mix the left and right (and whatever else) into the one output.

Your whole post is difficult to read and seems to confuse many different ideas/topics.

The answer is, set the output the speaker is plugged into to mono. That's it. That will make the sound correctly come out of the single speaker.